# how to better format data pulled from api onto a ant design table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I'm trying to add a prefix of a dollar sign as well as commas to certain columns within an ant design table with data pulled from an api.

Here's what im going for, i can't seem to figure this and a couple other things out for the life of me:
[image]

```py
  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=250&page=1&sparkline=true&price_change_percentage=24hr')
      .then(res => {
          const data = res.data;
          this.setState({ data })
      })
  }
  render() {
    const { data } = this.state;

    const tableData = data.map(row => ({
      Rank: row.market_cap_rank,
      Name: row.name,
      Price: row.current_price,
      Change: row.price_change_24h,
      totalVol: row.total_volume,
      marketCap: row.market_cap,
    }))

    const columns = [{
      title: 'Rank',
      dataIndex: 'Rank',
      key: 'Rank',
    }, {
      title: 'Name',
      dataIndex: 'Name',
      key: 'Name',
    }, {
      title: 'Price',
      dataIndex: 'Price',
      key: 'Price',
    }, {
      title: '24hr Change',
      dataIndex: 'Change',
      key: 'Change',
    }, {
      title: 'Total Volume',
      dataIndex: 'totalVol',
      key: 'totalVol',
    },

...

<Table rowKey='Name' columns={columns} dataSource={tableData} size="small"/>
```

im also quite aware that the code ive written could be better and any tips or suggestions like regarding the key for the table or anything else, please let me know!

Comment: You can directly use `data` with ant table without mapping. `key` should be json object's actual key. Like in case of Rank, use `market_cap_rank` as key. `dataIndex` is where the value is, in this case `market_cap_rank`. If it had a nested key `value` that you wanted to show in table,  the `dataIndex` would be `market_cap_rank.value` but the key would still be `market_cap_rank`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this needs some formatting, i have tried it long back and the function i used was:

```
value => `$ ${value}`.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ',')
```

this will add $ and comma to appropriate places.
Thanks

Comment: yes this will be helpful thanks for mentioning this.

Answer (score 2):

As per the [documentation](https://ant.design/components/table/) of Ant Design Table (check the Column section), you have to use `render` in columns to do this. Example -

```
const columns = [
.....
{
  title: 'Price',
  dataIndex: 'Price',
  key: 'Price',
  render: (value, row, index) => {
    // do something like adding commas to the value or prefix
    return <span>$ {value.toLocaleString('en-US')}</span>;
  },
},
.....
```